# Does VLOS under Part 107 allow for glasses?

Tags: regulations, faa

I'm studying for the Part 107 exam, and one of the sample questions is "What vision aids can a Remote PIC or a Visual Observer use to help them maintain Visual Line-Of-Sight (VLOS) while flying an sUAS?" The answer is "None. VLOS must be maintained with no visual aids." Is this true? At significant distances, all I would see of a small drone without glasded would be a fuzzy dot in the sky. I could see it clearly with glasses, though. Is that enough for Part 107m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, per below citation. (Emphasis mine)

§ [107.31](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/107.31) Visual line of sight aircraft operation.

(a) With vision that is unaided by any device **other than corrective lenses**, the remote pilot in command...